# List items stack on top of one another, absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my navigation bar in the middle of the div in terms of width and height. This solution seems to do the job, except it stacks each item on the list on top of one another. I've read a few previous posts, and this seems to be something to do with the fact I'm using absolute positioning. But I can't really figure out a way round this.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

p+p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.site-navigation {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  /* Basically saying fit all children within the container */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.site-navigation figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.site-navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-navigation ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header class="container site-header">
  <div class="innercontainer site-header">
    <p> some text here </p>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="container site-navigation">
  <figure>
    <img src="nav.png" />
  </figure>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Repairs</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks @j08691 for turning it into a snippet :)

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `position:absolute` in `a` tag that's why it mess up.

Update css part

```
.site-navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute; /* Add this */
  left: 0px;  /* Add this */
  right: 0px;  /* Add this */
  margin: 0 auto;  /* Add this */
}
.site-navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
   /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 50%;*/
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

p+p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.site-navigation {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  /* Basically saying fit all children within the container */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.site-navigation figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.site-navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-navigation ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="container site-header">
  <div class="innercontainer site-header">
    <p> some text here </p>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="container site-navigation">
  <figure>
    <img src="nav.png" />
  </figure>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Repairs</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

p+p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.site-navigation {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  /* Basically saying fit all children within the container */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.site-navigation figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.site-navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-navigation ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.site-navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="container site-header">
  <div class="innercontainer site-header">
    <p> some text here </p>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="container site-navigation">
  <figure>
    <img src="nav.png" />
  </figure>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Repairs</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: remove ' display: inline-block ' for styling <li> and then remove ' position: absolute ' for positioning <a> .